# Usages Some Android Method

Tags: android

I want to update an Android project ... but some code is not recognized by me..

1. Why we are using Debug.startMethodTracing("text");
2. Why we are using Debug.stopMethodTracing();
3. What is Context,BaseContext in android?

Answer (score 1):

That is just a technique by which you get to know **memory allocations, Object creation** during a  Method execution... Its an **optimization technique** and needs some experience. Not needed for initial development..

**Update**

study [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and you will get lot more when you google it..